# reverse relationship for foreign key in django templates

Tags: django

I have 4 models

```
Class A
    name
Class B
    fk1 = FK(Class A)
Class C
    fk = FK(Class B)
Class D
    fk = FK(Class C)
```

And in templates i want to use reverse relationship over all these models

I tried this

```
{% for que in Class A items %}

{% for item in que.b.c.d_set.all %}
```

but note getting the result. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood the question will be something like:

```
{% for que in a_times %}
     {% for b_item in que.b_set.all %}
          {% for c_item in b_item.c_set.all %}
               {% for d_item in c_item.d_set.all %}
                   # stuff with d_item
               {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
     {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

That is because you are using ForeignKey instead of OneToOneField, and I suggest you use [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/models/#inheritance-and-reverse-relations)

In the view you can do this:

```
from app.models import A, D
from django.shortcuts import render

def view(request):
    data = {}
    a_itemsqs = A.objects.all() # here you filter A objects
    d_items = D.objects.filter(c__b__a__in=a_itemsqs)
    data['d_items'] = d_items
    return render(request, data, 'template.html')
```

Comment: This is the answer, but remember you'll be making a*b*c*d database calls (in other words, a lot).

Comment: I agree with Daniel, is better get the items in the view and not to do this in the templates

Comment: How can i represent the same thing in view? I mean reverse relationship in views

Comment: How can I know which of d_items that are related to each a_item. So that I can use it like:

    {% for a in a_items %}
      {% for d in d_of_this_a %}
        ...
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}

Comment: I suggest you make a question and don't put it like a comment